# Does the language on error message convey correct?

Tags: natural-language

We are developing carpool app. Does the language reflect politeness and accuracy in intension?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Km (kilometer) is a unit, not a quantity. Therefor you cannot use sentences like "buy kilometers", or "exchanging km".

Comment: km in our context is quantity. People exchange km as they drive each other. We can redeem km for cash. Please suggest.

Comment: How can km be a quantity? 1 km = 100000 cm. Now consider the following sentences: "I have a very large amount of centimeters", "Please give me you centimeters", "I would like to exchange my centimeters for cash". That does not make sense. The quantity you are looking for is travel distance!

Comment: Also, please don't ever use "Ok". It is not OK to use "Ok". In the worst case I am OK with "Okay", but never "Ok".

Comment: Done, understood OK, I will never use Ok. Good advice. Thanks.

Comment: @BartGijssens, how about SO using reputation ? Doesn't that too fall in the category of not making sense. But it does to us. To a traveller he is looking at not exchanging money, instead he is OK using virtual currency that means something. All this is my assumption, I am not a UX guy so feel free to differ. Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that "reputation" nor "money" are units. Units are: km, kilogram, km/h, psi, Liter,... Reputation and money can be considered as a quantity. Kilometer cannot.

Comment: Your logic makes sense. What do you recommend I change it to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use the word "mandatory"; "need" is better. Also, I'm not sure what the first alert about the KM is even supposed to convey to the user, so it's hard to give any suggestion on it.

Here are my suggestions for the other three alerts:

[image: Modified alerts for Siddharth]

Also, if the user must have a Home Location setup for the app to work properly, you may want to have them set that up upon the first launch of the app, not tell them they need to do something when it doesn't work. Give them a screen when they start the app up for the first time to input their Home Location.